# Appscript help onedit email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm pretty new with Appscript and i'm looking for a solution when I complete a task, appscript code on edit will allow me to email whatever email is in the column B with just a simple task email that states the task has been completed.

[image: 1]

This script does work but it emails just me whenever there is a change triggered.  I'd like it just to email the email address in Column B and not me.

i've tried several different scripts but i don't know it well enough to pinpoint the issue or even edit it to fit my needs

```
  function checkValue()
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("J:J").getValue();

if(valueToCheck="Approved")
{
 MailApp.sendEmail("joes@nhcares.com","Task Completed","1231323"+ 
valueToCheck+ ".");
}
}
```

this may be too simple of a script, it does email me on edit but I need to tweak it more

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. About `"Task Completed","1231323"+ valueToCheck+ "."` your provided script, do you want to use it as the subject? In that case, what value do you want to use for the email body?

Comment: I would just like to say Task Completed and current date

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I would just like to say Task Completed and current date`, I understood that you wanted to use the values of columns "A" and "I" as the email body. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, from `Appscript help onedit email` and `This script does work but it emails just me whenever there is a change triggered.`, in your expected result, you want to send the email when the column "J" is edited. Is my understanding correct? I deeply apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You are correct, I'd like an email to column B email address, if column J has the word Approved.  Or would it be easier to have a dropdown in Column J with the options Approved?

Comment: From `actually looks like it worked`, I could confirm that my proposed script resolved your question. But, about your new issue of `why would it not go to my work email address?`, in this case, I cannot clearly answer because I cannot understand your current situation. In this case, unfortunately, I think that my answer was not useful for your actual situation. So, I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I would like to study more.

Comment: Oh no, your solution did work but for some weird reason, it won't send to my work email. i'll look at this later but you have solved my problem. thank you so much for your help Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `your solution did work`, I'm glad your initial question was resolved. About your new issue of `it won't send to my work email.`, in this case, I would like to recommend to ask this situation to the administrator of the email server. Because in this case, I think that it might be an issue between the servers. For example, although I'm not sure, the specific header might be required to be included. I really apologize that I cannot clear answer to your new issue, again.

Comment: Although I could resolve your initial question, unfortunately, I cannot clearly answer your new issue. If you will separate your initial question and your new issue, I think that my answer can be used. In that case, I can reopen my answer. I apologize that I cannot clearly answer your new issue, again.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, this code MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Task Completed", "by My Name" + valueToCheck + ".", currentDate + "," + completeDate);        when I do edit the sheet and it does email me, i only get the current date and completed date but it doesn't show Task Completed or by My Name

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `One more question`, I would like to support you. But, I would like to recommend resolving your question in order. What about will you do your initial question and your new issue? If you cannot understand my English, I apologize. At that time, please tell me. I would like to modify my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkValue(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == 'Approved') {
    let msg = `${sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat().join('\n')}`
    MailApp.sendEmail(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2).getDisplayValue(), "Task Completed", msg);
  }
}
```

Use installable onEdit trigger

Comment: Thank you Tanaike and Cooper. Both examples will work for me and you both are amazing. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If I were to add another column just for email address instead of using the User field for email, would I change the rowStart to 3?

Comment: rowStart is part of the event object and it is the row that was just edited.  So I don't understand how adding a column to hold email address has anything to do with rowStart

Comment: this was a question for help since I don't know the app script language that well. just asking if I added a new column, where would I edit the code to look at that new column for the email address?